# How do you implement a web-based direct deposit/eCheck payment system?

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, payment

I'm trying to develop a site that will allow users to pay for services with eChecks that other users are offering.

The purchaser would pay money that would go into my account via direct deposit. The service provider could later withdraw money up to the amount they accumulated to their bank account.

Every time I ask payment gateway providers about this, they act like I'm speaking in a foreign language. Paypal told me that their API doesn't allow direct deposits or eChecks.

What sort of merchant account / gateway combination do I need to do this? Can you direct me to any specific companies? I use Python/Django to develop applications, do you know of any libraries that might assist me with this endeavor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm certain that you would not be able to do facilitated ACH/EFT transfers directly from one user's account to another user's account.  However, as long as there's a third party in between the two users, this should be possible.  But I'm assuming you'd want to do that anyways, so that you can get paid.  The trick is finding a provider that will do both withdrawals and deposits, since most providers only give you withdrawals.  I'd recommend at least talking to [BrainTree](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/); they're by far my favorite payment provider.  If they don't work out though, you might try [Alliance](http://www.allianceach.com/), however, I've never used them, so take that recommendation with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. I contacted Braintree and I'm waiting on a response from them. I'll post how it goes here once I hear back.

Also, if it works out and you happen to visit Orlando, I'll buy you TWO beers.

Comment: One of their customer service representatives directed me to this blog post: http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/blog/high-risk-mechant-account-third-party-payments-aggregation/ . Basically, it looks like it's possible, but it is considered to be high-risk and it would require some sort of negotiation to make it work.

The representative proposed http://braintreepaymentsolutions.com/payment-processing/multi-merchant/ as an alternative that would work well if the service providers already have or would be willing to sign up for their own merchant accounts.

Comment: That's partly why I sent you in the direction of BrainTree... it IS high-risk, and for that kind of thing, you want to be able to get someone on the phone who know WTF they're talking about, rather than having to deal with 4 tiers of support.

Comment: Braintree no longer offers this type of service. :(